# Black screen after booting

Tags: boot

I am looking for help, because I don’t know about computers much. I had to restart my notebook, and than my ubuntu won’t start and I don’t know what these things it is writing mean. If there is anyone who could help me with it I would be really happy.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO8DU.jpg)

Comment: If you have a *live* thumb-drive, eg. Ubuntu install media; I would boot that, and using a tool like `gparted` or `gnome-disks`, do a *file-system check* (`fsck`) of your hard drive partition(s).  It doesn't require a command (which is `fsck`) if you use `gparted` or `gnome-disks` (GNOME disk utility) as they are GUI tools. This will find the errors, and correct them, then your machine will boot normally.

Comment: FYI:   Ubuntu 16.04 LTS reaches it's EOL (*end-of-life*) in a few months, so don't forget you'll need to *release-upgrade* your system before the end of April 2021, or you risk using *unsupported* and *un-patched* software that may put your data at risk, if you use your machine online.  I don't know your OS & release (you didn't say), but your provided picture looks like a *Xenial* or 16.04 system.